# Android RecyclerView element shadow background strange behaviour on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, layer-list

I have `RecyclerView` with simple elements. RecyclerView element has 2 Textviews. I'm setting drawable as background for `RecyclerView` element to produce shadow effect on sides of element. Everything is working fine on Samsung galaxy S7, but on device which runs on Lolipop recyclerview's element sides sometimes get gray color randomly.

**This is how it looks on Lollipop:**

[image]

Grey border appears randomly as I scroll.

**This is my drawable file, which provides shadow effect:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#01000000" />
                <padding

                    android:left="3px"
                    android:right="3px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#02000000" />
                <padding
                    android:left="3px"
                    android:right="3px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#03000000" />
                <padding

                    android:left="3px"
                    android:right="3px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#04000000" />
                <padding
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#06000000" />
                <padding
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#06000000" />
                <padding
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                     />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#07000000" />

                <padding
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#08000000" />

                <padding
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        <padding
            android:left="@dimen/shadow_padding"
            android:right="@dimen/shadow_padding" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**This is `RecyclerView` element:**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2"
android:paddingTop="12dp"
android:background="@drawable/border_sides"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/recyclerview_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/recyclerview_margin"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/key"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have idea why It's happening?

Comment: use 9 patch drawable instead of that `<layer-list>` drawable

Comment: @pskink Any idea how to generate 9patch only with shadows on sides?

Comment: why would you like to "generate" it? just use gimp / inkscape / whatever

Comment: How should it look like, can you attach a picture

Comment: Do you want to have a shadow around the whole recycler?

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder I had layout with a lot of views and it had performence issues so I made this window load as list. I cant put shadow arround whole recycler because recyclerview bound are visible. So I made seperate layouts for midle top, bottom elements with sperate shadows to make recyclerview appear as one element

Comment: `"I cant put shadow arround whole recycler because recyclerview bound are visible"` what is your goal actually? maybe post an image with the desired result?

Comment: It should look like `CardView` those bottom bound only visible after scrolling to the end. But this is not tghe problem. I achieved desired result, but the problem is that on LOLIPOP It's shadow is replaced by grey space

Comment: did you use 9 patches?

Comment: @pskink Don't have a lot of expierence with 9 patch. I know how to make simple 9 patch image, but dont know how to make shadow effects. And yes 9 patch probably would fix this problem. Because after little bit of research found out that lolipop has some issues with transparent colors

Comment: something like those: [top.9.png](https://pasteboard.co/GLeALca.png) [middle.9.png](https://pasteboard.co/GLeBa81.png) [bottom.9.png](https://pasteboard.co/GLeBpQF.png)

Comment: @pskink Yes, like this. Thank you a lot.

Comment: so is it what you need? did you try them?

Comment: @pskink Yes something like that, but shadow area should be bigger. Top one should have smaller shadow. Bottom bigger shadow. In general I want to reproduce CardView

Comment: so gimp to the rescue !!!

Comment: @pskink I appreciate your time and effort. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use **px**, use `dp` instead.
   Otherwise, the size will be different on various devices depending on their density
2. If you need a shadow around the whole RecyclerView - you can just wrap it with a CardView.
3. For having a shadow on the right and left use this drawable for your items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="start">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/black"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:width="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--margins should be the same as left and right shadow-->
    <item
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="end">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:endColor="@android:color/black"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:width="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Feel free to change width and gradient colors

Comment: The problem is still the same with your drawable aswell. I think underlaying problem might be that i use transparent colors inside drawable

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the background. Add your layout code as well as ViewHolder

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but I'm pretty sure my code is fine and I'm just looking to fix issue on lolipop. My code is working fine on other OS, but just LOLIPOP